# Is it true that any electrostatic charge density can be represented by Dirac Delta function? Give me a general example

Tags: electrostatics, charge, dirac-delta-distributions

My college professor said that any charge density can be replaced by Dirac Delta function but how I want to know.

Answer (score 2):

A Dirac delta function $q\delta^3(\vec{r}-\vec{r_1})$ represents a point charge $q$ at $\vec{r_1}$. A *sum* of Dirac delta functions represents a *collection* of point charges. All electrical charge in nature exists as the charge of elementary point particles such as quarks and electrons, so in that sense Dirac delta functions are sufficient *in principle* to represent any classical charge distribution.

*In practice*, delta functions are of little use when considering, say, a collection of $10^{23}$ charges in a macroscopic piece of matter. So we instead pretend that charge is distributed *continuously* in space as a charge *density* $\rho(\vec {r})$. It is just an approximation, but it is a very good approximation unless we care what is happening at a microscopic level.

Answer (score 1):

Dirac Delta function is defined by integral:
$$
f(r)=\int f(x)\delta(r-x)dx
$$
for any ("nice") function $f$.

Having point charge $Q$ at position $r$, the charge density $\sigma$ might be therefore written:
$$
\sigma(\vec{x})=Q\delta(\vec{r}-\vec{x})
$$
where $\delta(\vec{r}-\vec{x})=\delta(r_1-x_1)\delta(r_2-x_2)\delta(r_3-x_3)$ and $(r_1, x_1, ...)$ are componets of given vectors in cartesian coordinate system.

Then the charge inside any volume might be computed by:
$$
\int_{V;\vec{r}\in V}\sigma(\vec{x})dV=Q
$$
$$
\int_{V;\vec{r}\notin V}\sigma(\vec{x})dV=0
$$
as it should. So if we have n point charges + contiuous charge distribution with charge density $\sigma'$, the whole charge density might be written as:
$$
\sigma(\vec{x})=\sigma'(\vec{x})+\sum_{i=1}^n Q_i \delta(\vec{r}_i-\vec{x})
$$

For continuous charge distribution just write:
$$
\sigma(\vec{x})=\int \sigma(\vec{r})\delta(\vec{r}-\vec{x})dV
$$
Which might be sometimes usefull to plug into differential equations.